# What is the proper way to raise an exception for invalid property settings?

Tags: redhawksdr

I am writing a component that reads data from a specific filetype. Currently, it has a property for filepath - I would like for this block to quit as hard as possible when passed an invalid file/no file found.

Throwing an exception causes it to stop execution, but also deletes the block from the chalkboard while I am testing (?), which makes me think there is a more "approved" way to do it.

My current solution is something like:

```
LOG_ERROR( MyReader_i, "Unable to open file at " + Filepath );
return FINISH;
```

Is there another way to stop if something is wrong, that will hopefully stop all downstream processing as well?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Data Reader component in the basic components?  It also has a file path as an input.  It deals with this during the onConfigure call as shown below:

```
def onconfigure_prop_InputFile(self, oldvalue, newvalue):
    self.InputFile = newvalue
    if not os.path.exists(self.InputFile):
        self._log.error("InputFile path provided can not be accessed")
```

And then again in the service function by returning NOOP.

```
def process(self):

    if (self.Play == False):
        return NOOP
    if not (os.path.exists(self.InputFile)):
        return NOOP
```

This isn't the only way to deal with invalid input however.  It's a design decision that is up to the developer.

If you'd like additional components down stream to know about an issue elsewhere in the chain, you have a few options.  You could use the End of Stream bit, available in bulkio port implementations, to signal to down stream components that there is no additional data.  They can then use this information to clean up and shut down.  You could also use messaging to send a message out to an event channel and anyone who has subscribed to this event channel can be made aware of the message.   Again, it's a design decision.